# SAPUI5: How to create a Foreign Key link between two Tables in HANA

Tags: javascript, sapui5, hana

as the following titles states,

I do have Two Tables first one looks as the following:

```
COLUMN TABLE "FirstTable"(
    "exampleId" INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL,
    "Name" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("exampleId")

) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE;
```

and Second Table, which should have the Primary Key of FirstTable as a Foreign Key, so that a link between those two tables is established.

SecondTable:

```
COLUMN TABLE "SecondTable"(
    "scndID" INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL,
    "exampleId" INTEGER CS_INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("scndID"),
    FOREIGN KEY("exampleId")

) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE;
```

**Issue**: FOREIGN KEY doesn't work / isn't recognized.

**Question**: How to create a link between two tables with Foreign Keys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close with the syntax you chose.
All that is missing for the second table is to let HANA know what table the foreign key should belong to.

You need to add the `REFERENCES` expression to the `FOREIGN KEY` expression.

This is explained in the documentation [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228.html).

```
create COLUMN TABLE "SecondTable"(
    "scndID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "exampleId" INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("scndID"),
    FOREIGN KEY("exampleId") REFERENCES "FirstTable"
);
```

BTW: good choice to make all columns `NOT NULL`! It's a common mistake to leave the default of NULLABLE and to then have to deal with `NULL`s all over the place.

I would recommend to *not* include the column store data types (*CS_INT*) in your code - that's just confusing and don't add anything of value.
Likewise, use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` unless there is a good reason for not doing it.

Comment: Thank your for your answer!!! I referenced it like in your example, however it delievered an Error which looks as the following: `Error: com.sap.hana.di.table: "db://FirstTable": this artifact type must not have references to other objects [8250014]        at "src/data/tables/SecondTable.hdbtable" (0:0)     Error: com.sap.hana.di.table: Precompiling "src/data/tables/SecondTable.hdbtable"... failed [8212143]       at "src/data/tables/SecondTable.hdbtable" (0:0)`

Comment: Ok, you seem to be using the `.hdbtable` development design-time object for **XSA**. This, in fact, does not support foreign keys. If you want to use a foreign key concept and want to use the XSA design time objects, then using **CDS** entities and **Associations** is the way to go. Otherwise, you can always use plain SQL and use the command I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From SAP HANA 2.0 SPS 04 You can add .hdbconstraint file which allows defining (only) foreign-key.

```
CONSTRAINT SECOND_TABLE_F_KEY
ON SecondTable
FOREIGN KEY (exampleId) REFERENCES FirstTable(exampleId) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Documentation
https://help.sap.com/viewer/3823b0f33420468ba5f1cf7f59bd6bd9/2.0.05/en-US/bda54706fbda4910908871743b675ad1.html